# Authorize signalR Hub not connected in ASP Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

Authorize signalR Hub not getting connect to hub with front end angular, unable to invoke jwt access token to hub connection. How to connect Authurized signalr hub in asp core with angular project 
i have the following code in my project,

Here my Code

```
    public class Startup
    {
    readonly string CorsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: CorsPolicy,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()

                     .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:1234")
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSignalR()
        .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
        {
            options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });

       //jwt token
        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.SaveToken = false;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateIssuer = false,
               ValidateAudience = false,
               ValidateLifetime = true,
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

               ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
               ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
               ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
           };

           options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
           {
               OnMessageReceived = context =>
               {
                   var accessToken = "Bearer " + context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                  var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                      (path.StartsWithSegments("/connecthub")))
                  {
                    //  Read the token out of the query string
                      context.Token = accessToken;
                  }
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
              }
           };

       });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDatabaseContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<signalR_Hub>("/connecthub");
        });


       }
    }
}
```

This my Hub connection

```
[Authorize]
public class sample_Hub :Hub
{
}
```

This my controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Putfilecreations(string id, filecreations filecreations)
    {
        var entity = _context.file_creations.Where(x => x.file_creation_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        entity.client_type_id = filecreations.client_type_id;

         _context.file_creations.Update(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("FileUpdated", entity);
        return Ok(entity);
    }
```

This my Angular code for connect Hub

```
   this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(environment.baseUrls.server + 'connecthub')
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
  .build();
```

Comment: What error you have on the client console?

Comment: cors origin error,but i used enable cors in controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `CORS` this way, the order is important:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy, builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:1234"")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
});
```